# Spring Roo: Add multiple cross field validation annotation list (JSR-303 Bean Validation)

Tags: list, validation, annotations, constraints, spring-roo

In order to develop a roo advanced addon 
to provide cross field validation / constraints
we use SpELAssert to make a little shortcut.

To make the whole thing work with multible constraints
on certain fields its necessary to manage them in a list.

This type/style of annotation and FieldMatch is quite simular to the us.

Apparently it renders it as a "$List" (inner interface?) instead of ".List" and is not working.

I'm lost...

```
    package cz.jirutka.validator.spring;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
    import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
    import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;
    import javax.validation.Constraint;
    import javax.validation.Payload;

    @Documented
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({METHOD, FIELD, TYPE})
    @Constraint(validatedBy = SpELAssertValidator.class)
    public @interface SpELAssert {

            String message() default "{cz.jirutka.validator.spring.SpELAssert.message}";
            Class<?>[] groups() default {};
            Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

            String value();
            String applyIf() default "";
            Class<?>[] helpers() default { };

            @Target({METHOD, FIELD, TYPE})
            @Retention(RUNTIME)
            @Documented
            @interface List
            {
                    SpELAssert[] value();
            }
    }
```

**EDIT 1** for further explanations

Now - create annotation (type) with:

```
    // Create JavaType instance for the add-ons trigger annotation
    JavaType rooSpELAssert = new JavaType("cz.jirutka.validator.spring.SpELAssert");
```

Or

```
    // Create JavaType instance for the add-ons trigger annotation
    JavaType rooSpELAssert = new JavaType(SpELAssert.class.getName());
```

Result:

```
    @SpELAssert()
```

But howto:

```
    @SpELAssert.List()
```

Failed idea:

```
    JavaType rooSpELAssert = new JavaType(SpELAssert.List.class.getName());
    //==> @SpELAssert$List()
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Could you simplify the use case?

Comment: I droped a Edit #1 for you.